# Wso2 MI HTTP protocol violation : Not a valid protocol version

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

- List item

The payload becomes empty whenever it goes to backend. I have placed logger in  integration im able to see payload .when it comes to backend its becoming null .i have python django (server is my localhost).IN MI CONSOLE IM GETTING THIS

```
ERROR.ERROR {TargetHandler} - HTTP protocol violation : Not a valid protocol version: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" For : 127.0.0.1:8000 org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Not a valid protocol version: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN".127.0.0.1:8000
```

(this is my localhost server)because of its not deployed .am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following property before the Call mediator.

```xml
<property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: am using integration studio .payload factory => send => address endpoint.Response send.i tried placing property in insequence now request doesn't go to backend.@ycr